# Ordenar array de strings por longitud creciente

Tags: javascript

Cuando utilizo este código lo pruebo en la consola y funciona bien, pero cuando lo pruebo dentro de una función me salta `undefined`:

```
let arrayOfStrings =["You", "are", "beautiful", "looking"]

arrayOfStrings.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.length - b.length
})
```

El ejercicio en sí es este:

```
function sortArray(arrayOfStrings) {

// Recibes un arreglo de strings.
// Debe retornar un nuevo arreglo, pero con las palabras ordenadas en orden creciente a partir
// de la longitud de cada string.
// [EJEMPLO]: ["You", "are", "beautiful", "looking"]  ---> [“You", "are", "looking", "beautiful"]
// Tu código:

  arrayOfStrings.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.length - b.length);
  });
}
```

Comment: Te falta colocar al final del todo el return, es decir `return arrayOfStrings`, ya que tu función sortArray no está retornando nada lo que es lo mismo que `undefined`

Comment: Tu función no está retornando nada, falta colocar un return al `arrayOfStrings`.

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow, te dejé el primer voto positivo. Te invito a hacer el [tour] y así ganar tu primera medalla. También date una vuelta por el [help], encontrarás muchas información util. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Como te hemos mencionado en los comentarios, el problema es que tu función `sortArray` no tiene retorno, debes agregarlo

```js
function sortArray(arrayOfStrings) {
//  v---Este return te falta  
 return arrayOfStrings.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.length - b.length);
  });
}

let arrayOfStrings =["4444", "333", "22", "1"]

let sortedArray = sortArray(arrayOfStrings)
console.log("ordenado", sortedArray)
console.log("original", arrayOfStrings)
```

---

Un dato a tener en cuenta sobre la función `sort` es que modifica el array original (como se puede observar en el ejemplo anterior), haciendo que el retorno sea algo redundante e inútil. Esto tiene que ver con la "mutabilidad" y es algo que muchos tratamos evitar.

Entiendo que la pregunta está en un contexto de desafío y con lo anterior ya estaría respondida, pero para otros que tengan la misma duda, la solución pasa por clonar el array original para esto podemos usar [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone):

```js
function sortArray(arrayOfStrings) {
 let clon = structuredClone(arrayOfStrings)
 return clon.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.length - b.length);
  });
}

let arrayOfStrings =["4444", "333", "22", "1"]

let sortedArray = sortArray(arrayOfStrings)
console.log("ordenado", sortedArray)
console.log("original", arrayOfStrings)
```

Otra alternativa es usa la nueva función [toSorted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted), que como no podía ser de otra manera aún no está soportada en Firefox

```js
function sortArray(arrayOfStrings) {
 return arrayOfStrings.toSorted(function (a, b) {
    return (a.length - b.length);
  });
}

let arrayOfStrings =["4444", "333", "22", "1"]

let sortedArray = sortArray(arrayOfStrings)
console.log("ordenado", sortedArray)
console.log("original", arrayOfStrings)
```